# Why DateTime is ISerializable returns false in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, unity-game-engine, mono

I have tried the below code in multiple c# versions and works as excepted:

```cs
System.DateTime date = new System.DateTime (1024);
Console.Write (date is System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable);
```

Outputs:

```cs
True
```

but when i run it in Unity it returns false and the code goes wrong:

```cs
System.DateTime date = new System.DateTime (1024);
UnityEngine.Debug.Log (date is System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable);
```

Outputs:

```cs
False
```

I would like to detect if the object is ISerializable and then go forward and serialize it using GetObjectData method but when i try it upon DateTime in Unity it returns false while it should return true because DateTime is implementing ISerializable.

Unity uses .NET 3.5 and Mono (i don't know which mono version).

The code works fine in .NET 4.5.

[**Try it online**](http://rextester.com/FEHU43848)

Comment: Have you tried with `date.GetType().IsSerializable` ?

Comment: I would like to use the GetObjectData method.

Comment: And what is this `GetObjectData` method? You haven't show that and Unit does not have it either ( at least from what I see in documentation ).

Comment: It is a method that derived from ISerializable interface. the DateTime is implementing ISerializable interface but when i try `date is ISerializable` it returns false instead of true.

Comment: So you want to make "your own" serialization by wrapping the standard .NET serialization?

Comment: Yes, i am making Json and Binary serialization library and i want to use ISerializable.

Comment: Then you have to rewrite some classes that do not implement `ISerializable`, `DateTime` for example and implement it on your own. I don't see any other option because you cannot rewrite .NET libraries used by Unity.

Comment: If it would implement `ISerializable` then it would return `true` and you got `false` instead. Reference to [this page](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b) and rewrite it on your own. Then it will be `ISerializable`.

Comment: Could you give me a reference link? where you find it? i can't see it in the link you provided in answer.

Comment: You are asking for evidence they are different? But you **already** have that evidence. You have identified that `DateTime` does not implement `ISerializable` in Unity. That is the whole premise of your question. Have a read of `https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html` under `Container field types that can be serialized` - note that `DateTime` is **not** listed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html states:

> #### Serialization rules
>
> Serializers in Unity run in a real-time game environment. This has a
>   significant impact on performance. As such, serialization in Unity
>   behaves differently to serialization in other programming
>   environments. Outlined below are a number of tips on how to use
>   serialization in Unity.

*Alas serialisation of `DateTime` is not supported by Unity.*

If you need `DateTime` serialization then you may wish to have another `long` property that is kept in sync with the `DateTime` via [`ToFileTimeUtc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FromFileTimeUtc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx). Or implement [custom serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html).